# Getting away with only writing target_link_libraries(not specify include path) in CMakeLIsts.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I found that when I use `target_link_libraries` in CMaksList.txt , I get to ignore the include path(`target_include_directories`) and run the application successfully for example :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
add_executable(test test.cpp) #or add_library(test SHARED test.cpp)

target_link_libraries(  yolo
                        ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

And it turns out that everything works correctly and I am able to run application without any problem. Here`${OpenCV_LIBS}` and `${InferenceEngine_LIBRARIES}` is just`.so` file locate in somewhere in the system.

I would like to know why this is working ? In the other word, **What kind of information  does .so file contain** ? Does it contains include path ? How does this work behind the scene ?  Thanks !

Comment: If you run on Linux, usually you do not need to target_include_directories for stable header files in /usr/include (I apply "stable" to unversioned file paths.)

Comment: `.so` is a shared object file (dynamic/shared library), contains compiled code of the library.

Comment: @kiner_shah So how does the system know where to find header file of opencv ?

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer: There are several "system" include paths, which a compiler looks in any case. If your OpenCV headers are under one of these paths, then compiler will find them without any option. A shared object (`.so`) doesn't contain information about include paths.

Comment: I think I found the reason when using find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)  it adds the header files in the include path.

Comment: No `find_package` doesn't make any changes to the compiler settings, I bet if you remove `target_link_libraries` from your cmake file then it will still compile and just fail to link, opencv must be on your system include path

Comment: `find_package` probably just sets some variables (like `OpenCV_LIBS`) which indicate the paths to the libraries and header files.

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer, for your question, system knows the path of header files when you specify it using commands like `include_directories` or `target_include_directories`.

Comment: @kiner_shah However, if I delete the line  "target_link_libraries" , I would have a problem when including <opencv2/opencv.hpp>. Do you know the reason for it ?

Comment: @AlanBirtles No, if I delete the line "target_link_libraries" , I would have a problem when including <opencv2/opencv.hpp>.

Comment: Don't delete `target_link_libraries`, just add the `target_include_directories` and try to build the code.

Comment: @kiner_shah check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71201940/different-building-process-in-cmake-w-o-target-link-libraries-cause-the-problem ,what really confuses me is why w/o target_link_libraries cause include issue ?

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer, yeah was reading that only :-) I will try.

Answer (score 3):

The CMake docs for [`target_include_directory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) state:

> The INTERFACE, PUBLIC and PRIVATE keywords are required to specify the scope of the following arguments. PRIVATE and PUBLIC items will populate the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of . PUBLIC and INTERFACE items will populate the INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES property of <target>.

The documentation of [`INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.html#prop_tgt:INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES) states:

> Targets may populate this property to publish the include directories required to compile against the headers for the target. The target_include_directories() command populates this property with values given to the PUBLIC and INTERFACE keywords. Projects may also get and set the property directly.

> When target dependencies are specified using target_link_libraries(), CMake will read this property from all target dependencies to determine the build properties of the consumer.

In short, the libraries in `opencv_LIBS` likely each specified their public headers (those that *you* will `#include` as a user of the library) via `target_include_directories`, so that they would automatically be added to the include path when linked against. It's one of the nice things about CMake targets when set up correctly by library authors (which in this case it was).