# Different building process in cmake w/o target_link_libraries cause the problem of finding header file

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a `CMakeLists.txt` as shown below :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(Yolo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "$ENV{CXX_FLAGS} -O0 -Wall -g2 -ggdb2")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -Wall")

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(InferenceEngine REQUIRED)
find_package(ngraph REQUIRED)

add_library(yolo SHARED detector.cpp)

target_link_libraries( yolo 
                        ${InferenceEngine_LIBRARIES}
                        ${NGRAPH_LIBRARIES}
                        ${OpenCV_LIBS}
)
```

And when I delete the command `target_link_libraries`, the system can't find header file of opencv `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`，And I look into probelm and turn `VERBOSE=1` on while doing `make` , I found there's one main difference as shown below:

****With `target_link_libraries` the command generated by cmake would be :****

```
/usr/bin/c++ -Dyolo_EXPORTS -isystem /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/inference_engine/include 
    -isystem /opt/intel/openvino_2021/deployment_tools/ngraph/include 
    -isystem /opt/intel/openvino_2021.4.752/opencv/include -fPIC -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/yolo.dir/detector.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/yolo.dir/detector.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/yolo.dir/detector.cpp.o -c /home/twotwo/yolov5_LD/deploy/Yolo/product/detector.cpp
```

**Without `target_link_libraries` the command generated by cmake would be :**

```
/usr/bin/c++ -Dyolo_EXPORTS  -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/yolo.dir/detector.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/yolo.dir/detector.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/yolo.dir/detector.cpp.o -c /home/twotwo/yolov5_LD/deploy/Yolo/product/detector.cpp
```

Obviously, the the first case(with `target_link_libraries`) contains three additional `-isystem` for include path, I would like to know the logic behind this.As far as I know `target_link_libraries` basically only do linking job, why deleting this line would casue such problem ? Thanks

Comment: Can't find a dupe that I'm sure must exist, but a cmake library (not a regular static or shared library) has extra metadata, including include paths.  It's part of the modern cmake usage.

Comment: @StephenNewell Can you provide the refernce or doc for "cmake library (not a regular static or shared library) has extra metadata, including include paths" ?  I would like to read about it !Thanks

Comment: @Pro_gram_mer, is this the full output for `target_link_libraries`? I am wondering why it doesn't have something like `-lopencv` or `-lopenvino`.

Comment: @kiner_shah No, this is a command when executing add_library(yolo SHARED detector.cpp),I think it would first compile detector.cpp and link , the error happens here (before linking).

Comment: Exactly, I am wondering why with `target_link_libraries`, the final output doesn't contain `-lopencv`, etc.

Comment: This would be better as an edit to your original question